# C function output

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me the reason of getting 0 1 2 0 as output of below program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    e(3);

}

void e(int n) {

    if(n>0) {
        e(--n);
        printf("%d",n);
        e(--n);
    }

}
```

Output is 0 1 2 0

Comment: I wonder more how you got the code even running! Call a function which isn't known at compile time?!

Comment: Your code is ill-formed, you don't declare the `main` function properly. It *must* return an `int`, and as argument either take `void` or the usual `arg`/`argv` pair.

Comment: As for your problem, try to "run" the code *on paper*, or at the very least step through it line by line in a debugger.

Comment: This question came to my mind also but the output of the code is troubling me a lot .If you know the reason ,do share it with me .

Comment: This question was asked to me in a written test .I ran it online in codepad to see the output and I got 0 1 2 0 .I know why I am getting 2 0 but 0 1 ,I dont know.

Comment: The purpose of the question was to see if you understand something called recursion. Read up on that and the answer should become clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here' the flow of execution after `e(3)` is called from `main`.

```
e(3)
   e(2) 
      e(1) 
         e(0) ... return
         n is now 0
         print n. results in output 0
         e(-1) ... return
      n is now 1
      print n. results in output 1
      e(0) ... return
   n is now 2
   print n. results in output 2
   e(1) 
      e(0) ... return
      n is now 0
      print n. results in output 0
      e(-1) ... return
   return
```

And you see the output

```
0 1 2 0
```

Comment: @VartikaSingh - don't be shy about up clicking, or clicking answered on an answer if it helps you.  (little up and down arrows to the upper left of the answer)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the following is what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void e(int);

int main()
{
    e(3);
    return 0;
}

void e(int n)
{
    if(n > 0) {
        e(--n);
        printf("%d", n);
        e(--n);
    }
}
```

This is an example of a recursive function - a function calling itself. Here, at each call the parameter is decremented and the function is again called until the condition `n > 0` is not met. Then, the `printf("%d", 0)` happens. Now the second `e(--n)` will have no effect until `n` is at least `2`, since  the `if` condition cannot be passed with a value of `n` less than `1`. Further `printf()`s happen in the reverse order of the call as the function calls are removed from the stack. When the value gets to `2`, the second `e(--n)` gets a chance to make an effect thus printing `0`.

You need to learn about **recursion** (if you still haven't) and then you can get a good picture of how things happen. Also, it will help you if learn more about how the stack is set up when a function is called, and later returned.

Answer (score 0):

After denesting the code the reason for the results can be deduced in a single run in a debugger.

e() is recursive and called once before the print and once after. So before you hit your print statement you'll have to go through e again, and again, and again till it finally hits 0.

After that things start unlooping and you'll see prints popping up but it's still a big recursive mess because of the second call to e(n) in which n dips into the negative. I was rather grateful n was signed because if it was unsigned it would loop round to 2^32 and the program would get stuck in, pretty much, an infinite loop.

So yeah, TL;DR: run it through a debugger and learn from the FUBAR a recursion like this can cause.

Answer (score 0):

The 'flow' goes as follows:

```
main -> e(3)
e(3) -> IF(3>0)
{
    // n is pre-decremented to 2
    e(2) -> IF(2>0)
    {
        // n is pre-decremented to 1
        e(1) -> IF(1>0)
        {
            // n is pre-decremented to 0
            e(0) -> 0 is not > 0 so this call does nothing.
            // n is still 0 in this function call so...
            printf(0)  <-- The first '0' in the output
            // n is pre-decremented to -1
            e(-1) -> -1 is not > 0) so this call does nothing.
        }
        // n is still 1 in this function call so...
        printf(1)  <-- The '1' in the output
        // n is pre-decremented to 0
        e(0) -> 0 is not > 0 so this call does nothing
    }
    // n is still 2 in this function call so...
    printf(2)  <-- The '2' in the output
    // n is pre-decremented to 1
    e(1) -> (1 is > 0)
    {
        // n is pre-decremented to 0
        e(0) -> 0 is not > 0 so this call does nothing
        // n is still 0 in this function call so...
        printf(0)  <-- The second '0' in the output
        // n is pre-decremented to -1
        e(-1) -> -1 is not > 0 so this call does nothing
    }
}
```

It helps if you set the code out more clearly:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    e(3);
}

void e(int n)
{
    if(n>0)
    {
        e(--n);    //  First recursion here, but with n=n-1 on entry to the call.
        printf("%d",n);  // outputs (original value of n) - 1.
        e(--n);    // Second recursion here, now with n=n-2 on entry to the call.
    }
}
```